# WeatherData and TimeSeriesModelFit

Tags: time-series

with

```
city = CityData[{"Bremerhaven", "Bremen", "Germany"}];
```

and

```
BHVTemperatureData = WeatherData[city, "MeanTemperature", {{2000}, {2013}, "Month"}];
```

I get a TimeSeries object with 168 data points. These points are months and therefore these data should be uniformly spaced (12 per year).
But

```
tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[BHVTemperatureData];
```

gives the message "The data is not uniformly spaced ...".

Questions:
a) Can this unexpected message be explained?
b) Is there a way to retrieve a list of points in time/data from the TimeSeries object to exlain what is saved in this object type?

Best regards
Volker

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

At least on V9:

```
DateDifference @@@ Partition[BHVTemperatureData[[All, 1]], 2, 1]
(* {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ... *)
```

Shows that the data is not "equally spaced"

Comment: In mma10 this statement produces a long error message "Part::partd ...". Did they change the data structure of this type?

Comment: @Volker Can't test it here,but perhaps something like `DateDifference @@@ Partition[BHVTemperatureData["Times"], 2, 1]`

Comment: thanks, that works. I would never found this solution. Are you a relative of the famous east-roman general of the 6th century?

Comment: @Volker I am him